# Mask for only negative numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

How to build a mask for user entry only negative values in DevExpress/WinForms  TextEdit component?

I am trying to do this, but with no success:

[image]

[Same question here, but this solution is not working](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T307909)

I think it's a bug.

Comment: If you *think it's a bug*, you should be talking to DevEx, because we can't do anything about it. However, you *did* read the follow-up comments to the answer in the post you linked at the DevEx forums, which offers an alternate solution as well, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx mask type : `-[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9-]*`

[image]

or you can handle `EditValueChanging` event like this :

```
private void textEdit1_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !e.NewValue.ToString().Contains("-");
}
```

Comment: this mask allow positive numbers.

Comment: begin mask with `-` like answer .

Comment: I tried this hack, but when I get the value of the property EditValue, it is positive, I know I can make another hack to change the value to negative but I am reluctant to do this.

Comment: This solution works, but still uses a hack. I need automatic thousands separators as the user types the value. Still thank you for the effort to help guy.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with numbers, I suggest you use [SpinEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSpinEdittopic). To limit it to accept only negative numbers, use the [RepositoryItemSpinEdit.MaxValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemSpinEdit_MaxValuetopic) and [RepositoryItemSpinEdit.MinValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemSpinEdit_MinValuetopic) properties.

```
spinEdit1.Properties.MaxValue = -1;
spinEdit1.Properties.MinValue = decimal.MinValue;
```

If you need TextEdit, I suggest you use Abdellah's mask. So that you get TextEdit.EditValue as a number instead of a string, use the [ParseEditValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_ParseEditValuetopic) event.

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "-[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*";
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.RegEx;

private void textEdit1_ParseEditValue(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ConvertEditValueEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Value is string) {
        e.Value = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the mask on textedit? (without hacks)

Comment: In this case, I think Abdellah's mask is the most suitable. I've modified my answer to include an addition solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

In your form load :

```
TextEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "-#0.0000";
TextEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;
TextEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = false;
TextEdit1.Properties.EditFormat.FormatString = "-#0.0000";
```

And handel the event "`CustomDisplayText`" of your textEdit :

```
private void TextEdit1_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
          if ((e.Value != null) && !e.Value.Equals("")) 
           {
               e.DisplayText = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value).ToString("-#0.0000");
           }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`txtEdit.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "\\d-";`

Which version of DX do you use ?